# PHP mail() - Exchange 2003 doesn't receive email

Tags: php, email, exchange-server

I have a PHP mail() script that sends a HTML email that contains embedded images.

The code is basically this:

```
mail($to, $subject, $message, $headers);
```

The headers are like so:

```
MIME-Version: 1.0
Content-Type: multipart/mixed; boundary="--a9cf4407bac7d49ebd2d94af284cb0d8"
From: Myname <name@domain.co.uk>
Reply-To: name@domain.co.uk
```

The email delivers fine to all outlook.com and gmail.com addresses. I've tested however when sent to our office which runs Microsoft Exchange 2003 the email doesn't deliver.  It doesn't even reach the logs which baffles me.  Exchange isn't blocking the email, it isn't even receiving it.

Is there a known PHP / Exchange 2003 conflict? Or is the issue elsewhere?

I'm happy to supply more code if needed.

Comment: Hi, there can be many reasons for that, is POP3/IMAP port closed on your office mail server. Please check that first.

Comment: Hi Sourabh! I've checked and that port is open.  It's quite confusing - I'm no Exchange expert :(

Comment: Hi, as you are saying in your question that there is no log being recorded in your mail recieving server then it means that mail it is not even reaching your mail server. Use this link to scan open ports for POP3/IMAP. See if it shows shows open. And do you receive mails from other services like gmail, etc

Comment: If I use the PHP script to send to an outlook.com account and then manually forward the email to exchange the email comes through

Comment: Also was there supposed to be a link in your last comment? I can't see it

Comment: yes there was supposed to be a link, please use this link sorry about that: http://www.yougetsignal.com/tools/open-ports/

Answer (score 0):

You seem to be using php's native mail function. It is often cumbersome to configure and troubleshoot.

You may save yourself a lot of time by looking into PHPMailer or Swift Mailer. These libraries are constantly maintained and fixed to stay compatible with exchange and other systems.

Also, with exchange it may be easier for you to set up an email account on it and let your application use it.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same symptoms a few years back and if your problem is the same as mine you'll be surprised to find out it has nothing to do with your code.

In my case I was sending mail from from an internally hosted web server to an also internally hosted mail server. The web server was in the DMZ interface(a firewall/networking term) and the mail server was on the internal interface. Each interface operates on a different IP subnet (again networking stuff). The DNS for the mail domain (mail.ourdomain.com) resolved to the external IP of our firewall--which is configured to route that traffic to the internal mail server. However, that configuration only worked for traffic coming from the outside interface (external traffic). Traffic originating from the DMZ interface (mail sent from our webserver) could not be routed to the internal mail server.

You can do a quick check to see if you have the same problem. SSH to your web server and attempt to ping the mail server using the dns name.

```
ping mail.domain.co.uk
```

If you get a response, then this may not be the same problem.

Otherwise check with whoever is in charge of the firewall / network security and work with them to figure out what you need to do to get traffic from the webserver to the mail server. In our case we added a hosts file entry for mail.domain.com resolving to the internal IP of the mail server instead of the external IP.